# How to dynamically build a multiple taxonomy query loop within a post type's single loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, loop

This question is a little different then the others floating around here. The most similar one is "[How to get the parent's taxonomy ?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11945/how-to-get-the-parents-taxonomy)".

I have a music cms setup that utilizes two post types: *album* and *album media* and a few taxonomies: *genre*, *year*, and *artist*. In the footer of every *single-album.php* post I want to display the corresponding *album media* template and do this dynamically. There is only one *album media* post for every one *album*.

Both post types are associated with the three taxonomies. How can I write a loop inside another loop that automatically/dynamically obtains the associated taxonomies of it's parent post type?

For example: An *album* called "Dark Side of the Moon" is associated with taxonomies rock, 1973, and Pink Floyd. The *album media* "Dark Side of the Moon" is associated with the same taxonomies.

Within the main loop in *single-album.php* is another loop that looks for what three taxonomies the *album* is associated with and constructs a loop for "album-media". The contents of this loop could also be displayed as *single-albummedia.php*.

Can this be done? I have the feeling that I am over-thinking this   :)

Things this question involves:

- multiple taxonomy query
- loop within a loop
- custom taxonomies and post types

Comment: This looks like a great project! I've done some music sites myself and I love organizing the data related to music. I think I can be of assistance here, but I need to understand one thing more clearly, what exactly is album media? I think that'll help me wrap my head around this. Also, can you pastebin your current code for single-album.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment I also see some trouble understanding `album` and `album media` essence. You are also mixing up terminology a bit with `terms` and `taxonomies` (`term` is item in `taxonomy`).

So I am going to focus on your summary and leave to you how to put parts together:

1. *multiple taxonomy query* - taxonomy queries got much improved in WP 3.1 and now you can construct very elaborate things with [taxonomy parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).
2. *loop within a loop* - easier to say *secondary loop*, it doesn't matter where secondary loop is. because it shouldn't influence surroundings in any case. For [secondary loops either `WP_Query` object or `get_posts()` function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) are appropriate.
3. *custom taxonomies and post types* a little to generic point, there are plenty of nifty related functions. I suppose [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) sees a lot of usage, when taxonomies are involved.

Comment: Thanks for given me some better direction @Rarst ! I was able to build the dynamic loop and will post the code when I get it debugged.  :)